# HP Photosmart7280 won't work on the wireless network, tho it has before

Tags: wireless-networking, network-printer, imac

I've tried many ways to fix this problem, and as the cable receptacle doesn't work, I can't connect that way.  ANy ideas? Computer is imac running 10.9.4

Comment: The printer does not recognize the active wireless network and my router has 3. On the printer network configuration page, there is a mac address for the printer but the SSID is hpsetup and the ip address shows "no link". Network status is "offline" –

Comment: Also the mac address for the printer is different from the mac address for "hardware" in Network settings

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the wireless is correctly configured.  The wireless indicator should be lit and not blinking.  If it is on, print a Network Configuration page.  This will show you the printer IP address and the SSID you are connected to.  This helps to eliminate the wrong configuration being the issue.

Once you know it is configured correctly, can you ping the printer?

If it doesn't work now, please provide any error messages you are getting to help identify the issue.

Comment: The printer does not recognize the active wireless network and my router has 3.  On the printer network configuration page, there is a mac address for the printer but the SSID is hpsetup and the ip address shows "no link". Network status is "offline"

Comment: Also,the mac address for the printer is different from the mac address for "hardware" in Network settings –